# Can R list refer its own objects?

Tags: r, list, self-reference

Is it possible for a list in R to refer its own objects, while defining it?

Example:

```
ui_names <- list(
  gen_button = 'Generate Report',
  gen_description = sprintf("Press '%s' button to generate validation report.", gen_button)
)
```

Code above throws error `object 'gen_button' not found`. If I change gen_button to `ui_names$gen_button` then it shows `object 'ui_names' not found` error, which totally makes sense since the list is not defined yet.

I know I could go:

```
ui_names <- list(gen_button = 'Generate Report')
ui_names$gen_description <- sprintf("Press '%s' button to generate validation report.", ui_names$gen_button)
```

but I was wondering if is it possible for a list to refer itself during definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with `list()`. However, there is a function `tibble::lst()` that allows to do that. If you have a problem with `tidyverse` dependencies, this function has also been adapted in the package `poorman` (which only relies on base R):

```r
tibble::lst(
  gen_button = 'Generate Report',
  gen_description = sprintf("Press '%s' button to generate validation report.", gen_button)
)
#> $gen_button
#> [1] "Generate Report"
#> 
#> $gen_description
#> [1] "Press 'Generate Report' button to generate validation report."

poorman::lst(
  gen_button = 'Generate Report',
  gen_description = sprintf("Press '%s' button to generate validation report.", gen_button)
)
#> $gen_button
#> [1] "Generate Report"
#> 
#> $gen_description
#> [1] "Press 'Generate Report' button to generate validation report."
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything. I do not have problems with tidyverse and as I can see a list created by `tibble::lst` behaves the same way as base list :)